# No Sound on Ubuntu 21.04 Fresh Installation

Tags: ubuntu, audio, sound-card

I just installed ubuntu 21.04 and there is no sound, checked sound settings, Only dummy output is there. I am using a headphone connected with rare jacks on pc.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: problem solved.